# How do I calculate the anniversary date in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm using JPA2

I could have queried it in Ms Access in following [way](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?147082-How-do-I-calculate-the-anniversary-date-in-SQL-Ms-Access)

For example, to find out the anniversary in two years:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, 2, initialdate) AS Anniv
```

Or to find out how many years have passed since the initial date:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, initialdate, GETDATE()) AS YearsPassed
```

I'm not able to find function in `DATEADD` in JPQL

Could some one please help me getting similar effect in JPQL

Comment: Datediff is really bad for calculating the years that have passed.

Comment: JPQL supported sql functions: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/jpql_functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Session provides a [`doWork()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work)) method that gives you direct access to [`java.sql.Connection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). You can then create and use [`java.sql.CallableStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) to execute your function.

Here is an OracleDB function example:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER ); // or whatever it is
    call.setLong(2, id);
    call.setLong(3, transId);
    call.execute();
    int result = call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
  }
});
```

Or you calculate this within your programm logic.